# Add custom auto imports to vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

if I type `autorun` inside the code, vscode suggests me to auto import it from mobx:

[image]

I want to define some custom names for that for example if I type `_` somewhere in the code, I want vscode to suggest me to import `lodash`

or if type `PropTypes` I want vscode to suggest auto `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`

Is this possible?

I haven't written any vscode extensions yet, but I can take a swing at it if that's what it takes to complete this functionality

Thanks in advance for any help and guidance!

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Comment: I have same issue, so I just wrote quick-and-dirty extension, that allows to hardcode in the settings `"PropTypes": "prop-types"` and then provide suggestion for `PropTypes`, which adds import to the top of file. It needs some work to be done, like settings schema, settings reload, more careful autoimport insertion, but resolves my issue.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rulexec.custom-autoimport

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for this built into VSCode currently. Basically you're looking to define a list of names/aliases for default exports (i.e `import MyCustomName from 'lodash'`). Cool idea! I think you'd have to write a pretty low-level VSCode extension to accomplish this might end up being limited by the TypeScript compiler itself. Good luck!

Comment: I thought the solution might be writing an extension, tho I'd need some pointers, hence the question and the bounty here :)

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do is declaring it on a file and importing it from there:

`tailwind.ts`

```js
export { default as tailwind } from "tailwind.macro";
```

`someFile.ts`

```js
import tailwind from "~/tailwind";
```